# How to change the length of a column in a SQL Server table via T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am looking to find out how to alter a fields properties contained in an SQL Server 2008 table via an SQL script.

I'm looking to change the 'Length' property specifically.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean change the column datatype?

Comment: No, I want to change the column properties for a specific field.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So, let's say you have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(Col1 VARCHAR(10))
```

And you want to change `Col1` to `VARCHAR(20)`. What you need to do is this:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ALTER COLUMN Col1 VARCHAR(20)
```

That'll work without problems since the length of the column got bigger. If you wanted to change it to `VARCHAR(5)`, then you'll first gonna need to make sure that there are not values with more chars on your column, otherwise that `ALTER TABLE` will fail.

Comment: Remember to specify NOT NULL explicitly if desired. Otherwise it will default to NULL regardless of what the original specification is.

Comment: @JohnGilmer: Thanks, for telling about NOT NULL constraint. It helped me and saved lot of trouble.

Comment: just adding on the top of that, this will work as long as no other object in database is depending on this column